# Java No Such Element Exception Scanner Error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For this code, I'm supposed to ask an integer input from a user and print number is the highest and the lowest. However, on the line where I declare the variable "number" as an int, the console shows the error "java.util.NoSuchElementException". What is wrong with said line?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaxMin
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int largest = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number (-1 to quit):");
            int number = input.nextInt();

            if(number >= 0 && number >= largest)
            {
                largest = number;
            }
        
            if(number >= 0 && number <= smallest)
            {
                smallest = number;    
            }
        
            if(number == -1)
            {
                break;    
            }
            System.out.println("Smallest " + smallest);
            System.out.println("Largest " + largest);
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind showing the entire exception? Is it possible that because you created the Scanner, then printed to the output stream, that the newLine (\n) call is corrupting the nextInt() call? Try creating scanner after System.out maybe.

Answer (score 0):

This code is perfectly working fine in my IDE. However if you enter a large number you will get a different exception like this. Since integer range is from -2147483648 to 2147483647

```
Enter a number (-1 to quit):
21313132313
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "21313132313"
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2264)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at com.example.demo.Application.main(Application.java:25)
```